# Не работает якорь указывающий на другую страницу

Tags: html

Мне необходимо, что бы при нажатии на ссылку переходило на другую страницу в определенную её часть с формой.

Написал ссылку так:

```
<a href="https://site/#form">Перейти по ссылке</a>
```

И к форме приписал id:

```
<div class="formStyles" id="form">Здесь код формы</div>
```

При попытке перехода на сайт через url всё работает хорошо, но при нажатии на ссылку меня не переносит на ту страницу, хотя url ссылки отображается такой же

Как сделать что бы по ссылке переносило на другую страницу в нужную часть сайта?

Comment: Попробуйте путь так прописать <a href="/#form">Перейти по ссылке</a> И второе, Бутстрап подключен?

Answer (score 0):

Почему якорь не переходит на другую страницу не разобрал но просто использовал это решение на js

```
document.getElementById("anchor").onclick = function(){
  document.location.href = "https://site#form";
}
```

И ссылка заработала нормально, также ей в href прописал javascript:;